# Need to get all permutations of same-level nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My source data looks like this:

```
<Nodes>
  <Node id="abc">
    <Data id="123">
      <Value>Red</Value>
      <Value>Green</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data id="234">
      <Value>North</Value>
      <Value>South</Value>
    </Data>
  </Node>
  <Node id="xyz">
    <Data id="123">
      <Value>Red</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data id="234">
      <Value>North</Value>
      <Value>South</Value>
    </Data>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I need to get all permutations of values between the two data "id"s. So my output would look like this:

```
<Nodes>
  <Node>
    <Value>abc</Value>
    <Value123>Red</Value123>
    <Value234>North</Value234>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <Value>abc</Value>
    <Value123>Red</Value123>
    <Value234>South</Value234>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <Value>abc</Value>
    <Value123>Green</Value123>
    <Value234>North</Value234>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <Value>abc</Value>
    <Value123>Green</Value123>
    <Value234>South</Value234>
  </Node>      
  <Node>
    <Value>xyz</Value>
    <Value123>Red</Value123>
    <Value234>North</Value234>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <Value>xyz</Value>
    <Value123>Red</Value123>
    <Value234>South</Value234>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I can only use XSL 1.0. I can obviously use "for-each" on either the "123" or the "234" Data nodes, but I can't figure out how to back out and then get permutations of the other.

Comment: Could you explain the constrains here? Will there always be exactly two (or at least no more than two)  Data elements per Node?

Comment: No, there could be 1 or 10 or any number of Data nodes (both the 123 and the 234 nodes). And the values aren't actually "Red" and "Green" or anything simple like that. They're IDs that are 6 - 7 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Nodes">
    <nodes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node"/>
    </nodes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:variable name="node-id" select="@id" />
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Value">
        <xsl:variable name="current-value" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="current-id" select="../@id" />
            <xsl:for-each select="../following-sibling::Data/Value">
                <node>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="$node-id"/></value>
                    <value id="{$current-id}"><xsl:value-of select="$current-value"/></value>
                    <value id="{../@id}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
                </node>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
   <node>
      <value>abc</value>
      <value id="123">Red</value>
      <value id="234">North</value>
   </node>
   <node>
      <value>abc</value>
      <value id="123">Red</value>
      <value id="234">South</value>
   </node>
   <node>
      <value>abc</value>
      <value id="123">Green</value>
      <value id="234">North</value>
   </node>
   <node>
      <value>abc</value>
      <value id="123">Green</value>
      <value id="234">South</value>
   </node>
   <node>
      <value>xyz</value>
      <value id="123">Red</value>
      <value id="234">North</value>
   </node>
   <node>
      <value>xyz</value>
      <value id="123">Red</value>
      <value id="234">South</value>
   </node>
</nodes>
```

**Note**:

1. IMHO, storing *data* (the `id` values of the original parent `Data`
   nodes) inside *element names* is not good practice.
2. Untested with other configurations, because you didn't supply them.
3. If I'm not mistaken, these are *combinations*, not *permutations*.

Comment: I agree, but I have no control over the data I receive. I had to alter this a bit to work for my exact data set, but I got that done and it's working perfectly. Thank you so much!!!